# Build VLC for iOS, get the "FFTW3 lib not found. Set FFTW3_DIR to find it." error

Tags: ios, fft, vlc

I want to build vlc for iOS.

My environment is MacOS 10.8.3, Xcode4.6.2 with iOS6.1 SDK.
I cloned the vlc lib form https://github.com/videolan/vlc.git, cd into the /extras/package/ios, and run the build.sh in terminal, everything goes okay except when I start making the chromaprint, I got this error:

FFTW3 lib not found. Set FFTW3_DIR to find it.
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:114 (message):
  Neither FFmpeg with avfft.h nor FFTW3 found

This is because chromaprint needs the fft library, it will find FFMPEG and also FFTW3.

I want to use the FFMPEG for an fft calculation, so I have download a copy of ffmpeg source code and complied it,the libs and headers are in the directories: /Users/king/ffmpeg/complied/include and /Users/king/ffmpeg/complied/lib,
 then I set the FFMPEG_ROOT as /Users/king/ffmpeg/complied in the cmake/modules/FindFFmpeg.cmake, just before the  FIND_PATH() function.
something like : set(${FFMPEG_ROOT} /Users/king/ffmpeg/complied)
,I hope the FIND_PATH() can find the releated libs and headers, this doesn't work.

So my question is, How do i set the FFMPEG path or FFTW3_DIR for chromaprint?
Thanks in advance, I am really run out of my head!

Comment: If this is intended for a jailbroken iOS, why not just install vlc from cydia?

Comment: hi,demure, It's not for jailbroken, I am an iOS developer. I want to use vlc for playing ts stream

Comment: Nobody knows ? Can't believe!

Comment: I am having the same issue when attempting to build VLC for Windows 10. Did you ever figure out a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem on VLC Windows cross build.
After I upgrade cmake to 3.22.0, this problem is fixed.

I download latest cmake source code and build.

I also download fftw3 package and extracted under /home/[username]/fftw3.
Set FFTW3_DIR to ~/fftw3 by

> export FFTW3_DIR=/home/[username]/fftw3